# Social buttons not showing properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following footer:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <!--End container-->
</footer>
<!--End footer -->
```

I include the following on top:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/scrolling-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Font awesome CSS -->
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap social CSS --> 
<link href="css/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

However, when I open the HTML, all I see is this:

[image: footer]

How do I get the footer to show the correct buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, your fontawesome's fontface  path is wrong, you should put the fonts folder in the same path of your fontawesome.css, which is the default setting.

For more details, please refer to http://fontawesome.io/get-started/